# Isomorphism of $3$-by-$k$ matrices to a subspace of $7$-by-$1$ column vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be the space of all $3\times k$ matrices. Let $T$ be the space of all $7\times 1$ column vectors.

If $S$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $T$, what could $k$ be?

Here's so far I got....

Let $A$ = a subspace of $T$. Let $f:S\rightarrow A$ be an isomorphism.
Then $f$ is 1-1, onto.

Use $\DeclareMathOperator{\nullity}{nullity}\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}\dim(S)=\nullity(f)+\rank(f)$:

$\dim(S)=3k$, $\nullity(f)=0$, $\rank(f)\leq 7$.

So $k$ could be 1 or 2.

But I'm not sure whether $\dim(T)=7$, therefore $\dim(A)\leq 7$...

Thanks~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these matrices/vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$?

If so, then $T$ is definitely of dimension 7: a basis for it is the set of vectors $\vec{e}_1,\ldots,\vec{e}_7$, where $\vec{e}_j$ is the vector consisting all of $0$'s except for a $1$ in the $j$th row.

The nice thing about isomorphic vector spaces is that they always have exactly the same dimension: if $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$, with isomorphism given by $\phi:V\rightarrow W$, then $\vec{v}_1,\ldots,\vec{v}_k$ is a basis for $V$ if and only if $\phi(v_1),\ldots,\phi(v_k)$ form a basis for $W$.

Another nice fact is that any two vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ which have the same dimension are isomorphic: if $\vec{v}_1,\ldots,\vec{v}_k$ and $\vec{w}_1,\ldots,\vec{w}_k$ are bases for $V$ and $W$ respectively, then the map $\psi:V\rightarrow W$ by
$$
\psi(\alpha_1\vec{v}_1+\cdots+\alpha_k\vec{v}_k)=\alpha_1\vec{w}_1+\cdots+\alpha_k\vec{w}_k
$$
is an isomorphism, as is not too hard to show.

A final nice fact: any vector space of dimension $d$ contains vector spaces of dimension $1,2,\ldots,d-1$ as well; just look at the space generated by a a subset of the basis vectors.

So, really, the question that's posed to you is this: your space $S$ is of dimension $3k$. $T$ contains a vector subspace isomorphic to $S$ if and only if $T$ contains a vector subspace of dimension $3k$.  In turn, $T$ contains a vector subspace of dimension $3k$ if and only if $3k\leq 7$.  So, we must have $k=1$ or $k=2$ in this case.

I've given you a good roadmap, and some intermediate results which you may find useful; of course, I haven't formally proved them for you, so make sure you can do that if you're going to use them.